# plugin in android

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

---

errore...
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

Add these plugins in your build.gradle(Project:"ProjectName") file in the the plugins block and then sync your gradle.

Comment: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:
* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output
> Run with --scan to get full insights
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
 at -org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)